# Subfolders in subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain, subdirectory

I have a site: myname.host.com
I have a domain: www.myname.nl

I have some subfolders for different subsections but also completely unrelated websites.

How do I make sure in the DNS setup that:

- blog.myname.nl gets me to myname.host.com/blog/
- blog.myname.nl/archive gets me to myname.host.com/blog/archive
- blog.myname.nl/randomfolder gets me to myname.host.com/blog/randomfolder

Catch my drift?

I mean, getting www.myname.nl/blog/archive to work is easy. Cname + A record with IP do the trick. But how about the sub-domain + subfolder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Paths are not part of DNS. I don't believe there is any way to make them so. You'll need to do that in your server configuration (for example, Apache rewriting).